# Java Beginner logic error help needed

Tags: java, if-statement, input, output

I apologize in advance for my post. I decided to register tonight and this is my first post.

A little background about the question.

I am doing a little java project, where I need to take a name from user input, which is saved in a variable. the variable value must then display the output.

my question is. How is it done in java, using the (if) keyword, to use my code to create an if statement that voids my simple i_PlayerName method of any logic error.

to be more specific, how can I make sure that my program will only accept a string value, and if another data type is entered, an output message will be displayed " user input not accepted ".

lastly, what is this procedure called?

Thank you all :)

keep on coding the code.

```
public void i_PlayerName() {

    String playerName;

    Scanner i_playerName = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ENTER YOUR SHIP NAME");
    playerName = i_playerName.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your vessel has been named " + playerName);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to read a basic tutorial. [This one, for instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html).

Comment: This looks like a command line interface. whatever user enters will be considered of String type. You probably want to use something like StringUtils.isAlpha(playerName) to make sure only letters were entered or whatever validation logic you have. See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAlpha-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly. See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  My computer's keyboard only allows me to type `String` values.  I don't see what else the input could ever possibly be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant  *alphabets*  when you said only `strings` are allowed, this should do it.

```
public static void main(String[] Args) {
    String playerName = "";
    System.out.print("Enter ship name: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String i_playerName = scanner.next();
    System.out.println();
    char[] chars = i_playerName.toCharArray();
    boolean isChar = true;
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            isChar = false;
        }
    }
    if(isChar == true) {
        System.out.println("Your vessel has been named: " + i_playerName);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("User input is not accepted.");
    }

}
```

Comment: answer works just great. thank you for the prompt help. much appreciated.

Comment: @David-LeeIngham Please accept the answer if it helped. You're welcome. :)

Comment: Thankyou, sorry i have been away on holiday :) your answer is ticked

Answer (score 0):

when the scanner is reading if you assign it to a String type it will take the input as a String regardless if the user inputs numbers or Strings.  If you want to handle the scenario when user inputs value other than String you can do it with regular expression and if the input is not a match then output the error.  Use below method to check if input is a String.

```
public boolean isStringValue(String s){
    String pattern= "[a-zA-Z]*";
    return s.matches(pattern);
}
```

//use method above:

```
String input = scan.next();
if(isStringValue(input)){
//your code
} else {
//output some error
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `^` and `$` in the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. I've been on holiday the last few days so i apologize for the slow ticks.